# Having problems with my submit button in my php/html file

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, submit-button

I am starting now in this whole world of development and I created a PHP file with some HTML included.

in the beginning, the file was called `index.html`, but then I started using PHP in the file so I renamed it to `index.php`. Then I found a not so common name for my project and renamed it to `LoginProject.php`.

Everything is working perfectly except for my submit button.
When I press enter or click submit, the button in the file named `LoginProject.php` sends me to a "secondary" page called `index.html` (the original name I gave my project).

[Here you can see the error message I'm receiving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHjfM.png)
so you can see I'm talking about.

Can anyone help me change that?
Thanks,
B.

Comment: search about form action, and read this please How to ask a question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Make sure you've updated the `action` attribute in your `form` tag.

Comment: Post your code. Your problem is almos certainly in your `<form>` tag, but there's no way to tell

Comment: Thank you to everyone who tried to help me!
It was the `action` inside my `<form>` tag!

Answer (score 0):

check it

```
<form action="LoginProject.php" 
      method="POST"
      >
```